# Why is ffmpeg and vlc able run RTSP stream but gstreamer is unable to?

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg, streaming, gstreamer

When executing this command (gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://--- --gst-debug=3) I get this output:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0yft.png)

Not sure how to make sense of this because my RTSP stream is sending via TCP. Also, this rtsp stream works when launched on ffmpeg and vlc.

Any help is much appreciated!

Apologies if this is the wrong place to be asking such question.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: gstreamer is a subset of ffmpeg. I don't understand why [Lennard Poettering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Poettering) even wrote it. I'd try to avoid it.